# Using search and slice

Tags: javascript

I have a class defined as follows:

```
function Take(){
    Take.prototype.txt = "winter is coming"
}
```

Take has a function which chops off and returns a single word from the txt attribute

```
Take.prototype.single = function(){
    var n = this.txt.search(/\s/); //locate the first word
    var word = this.txt.slice(0, n); //slice that word out 
    this.txt = this.txt.slice(n); //txt now becomes everything after the word
    return word;
}
```

When I execute the single() one time, I get:

```
winter
```

and what's left in txt is

```
_is coming //underscore to display a space there
```

but if I execute the code again I get nothing, and txt still has

```
_is coming //underscore to display a space there
```

The second execution of single should return is, and txt should just have winter left in it.

Comment: Try typing `' is coming'.search(/\s/)` in the console, and I'll bet you you'd get zero as the string starts with a space.

Comment: And then you'd have `this.txt.slice(0, 0)`, which gives you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the search method returns the first index of the match. Given that you are looking for a single space character, the index it returns everytime after the first is `0` since the string now starts with a space.

I'd recommend changing the line before the return to the following:

`this.txt = this.txt.slice(n).trim(); //txt now becomes everything after the word`

Comment: Using your suggestion, the following outputs are winter is comin. The g for some reason is getting cut off of coming.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
var n = this.txt.search(/\s/); //locate the first word
```

`\s` is a space character, I think your regex is not valid to search a word.

Try `\S+` instead (`\S` = not a space character)

[image]

```
/\S+/.exec('winter is coming'); // returns 'winter'
/\S+/.exec(' is coming');       // returns 'is'
/\S+/.exec('  coming');         // returns 'coming'
```